# Implicit and Explicit Copy Constructor Call

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

Just curious to know whether there is any difference(apart from the syntax) between a implicit and explicit "copy" constructor call?

Eg.

`MyClass my2 = m1; //Implicit Call
   MyClass my3(my2); //Explicit Call`

Comment: See also http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No difference.**

Both call the same underlying method.